# What are the under documented differences between the 9.7" and 12.9" iPad Pros?

Tags: ipad

Besides size of course what are the differences between the 9.7" and 12.9" iPad Pros? I noticed the 9.7" has a camera bump.

Comment: You can see the differences at http://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/specs/ and http://www.apple.com/ipad/compare/ and therefore no need to be asking such a Basic Customer Support type question!

Comment: @user3439894 Those pages don't contain information such as USB port spec, RAM, tablet reflectivity, and which chargers work with the devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching the specs page, compare page, and other resources I have found these differences:

#### 12.9" iPad Pro

- Compared to A7:
  CPU: 2.5x faster
  Graphics: 5x faster
  **RAM: 4GB**
- 8 MP camera
- 1.2 MP Facetime HD Camera
- LTE
- Nano Apple SIM (removable)
- **USB 3** lightning port for use with the [USB 3 Camera Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-3-camera-adapter?fnode=97).

> The 12.9-inch iPad Pro transfers data at USB 3 speeds, while the
>   9.7-inch iPad Pro uses USB 2.

- Can be charged with the **29W USB-C** charger (the same one as the Macbook "one"). You will need the [USB-C to lightning adapter cable](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK0X2AM/A/usb-c-to-lightning-cable-1-m?fnode=97) as well.

> You can also use the cable with an Apple 29W USB-C Power Adapter to
>   take advantage of the fast charging feature on the 12.9-inch iPad Pro.

#### 9.7" iPad Pro

- New antenna lines instead of a plate for wireless connectivity
- Comes in Rose Gold
- 32GB LTE option
- Wide color display
- True Tone display
- "Hey Siri" functionality
- Compared to A7: CPU: 2.4x faster Graphics: 4.3x faster **RAM: 2GB**
- 12 MP/ 4K video camera with live photos, Retina flash, and focus pixels (with bump)
- 5 MP Facetime HD Camera
- LTE Advanced
- Embedded Apple SIM
- “lowest reflectivity of any tablet”
- **USB 2** lightning port